# When I run any project on visual studio, it runs it multiple times

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

When I start, or press F5 in Visual Studio, it will open run the project so many times, that Visual studio crashes, I can see a good 20 windows run at the same time before Visual Studio crashes.

Comment: Have you tried running VS in "safe mode": [/SafeMode (devenv.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx)?

Comment: Tried that just now, didn't help. I have to assume it is something to do with my Visual Studio 2013, because 2010, and 2012 work fine, it's just the 2013 edition which does this.

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a try to find out if a third-party package was doing someting strange. I thought maybe a faulty F5 key would do it, but I couldn't get it to go wrong by pressing F5 many times quickly. You can repair your VS installation from the "Programs and Features" control panel. Oh, and does it do this on a new project, or just existing ones?

Comment: Yeah, it's just really strange, I'm gonna try the repair, I'll report back if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Repairing didn't fix, and it does it to every project I have, or create on Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I believe the usual reply at this stage is to suggest uninstalling VS2013 and the .NET 4.5 framework, restart the computer, and re-install VS2013 and all its updates, and check Windows Update for any .NET 4.5 framework updates.